# Are these noun phrases single or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, quantifiers

I am very confused about which is the main noun in a noun phrase.
And I know that the verb should be in accordance with the main noun in the subject noun phrase in terms of the numbers.

> **Noun Phrase A.**
>
> the majority of people
>
> Q) The majority of people are/is?
>
> **Noun Phrase B.**
>
> several layers of meaning
>
> Q) Several layers of meaning are/is?

Is each phrase single or plural and could you explain why?

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **majority** of people **is**.

**Majority**--in this instance--refers a *single* group.  It is *singular*.

> Several **layers** of meaning **are**.

**Layers** is *plural*.  In addition to the *s* at the end of *layers*, the word *several* gives this away.

Comment: But, I checked the article A in a book and it says it is plural. Can you give me more explanation about it?

Comment: Are you referring to the article "a"?